# How to install OneDrive on ubuntu 13.10 x64

Tags: software-installation

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and I don't know how to install OneDrive on ubuntu 13.10 x64.

Comment: I am not sure, but is it not possible to run OneDrive on Linux with Wine? I have never tried it myself though.

Comment: You can always go to http://www.onedrive.com on your firefox. Even though this isn't ideal, it will allow you to browse, upload and download your data.

Comment: please refer [https://askubuntu.com/questions/676210/how-to-sync-onedrive-on-ubuntu-14-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676210/how-to-sync-onedrive-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 12):

You can't. One drive is a Microsoft service and, oddly enough, they don't support Linux but only Windows and OSX. Apparently, there is a [project](https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d) to port it to Linux which looks like it's worth trying, but it is still under development.

In the meantime, I recommend you use another cloud storage service, there are various that have Linux versions. See, for example, [here](http://bestonlinefilestorage.net/cloud-storage-for-linux/) and [here](http://www.cloudreviews.com/blog/linux-cloud-storage).

Comment: And it looks like Gnome is having [a library zapojit](https://github.com/GNOME/libzapojit)

Answer (score 2):

@terdon is right , you can use some alternatives to google drive like :

**Dropbox**

Dropbox was the first popular cloud storage service, and its client ecosystem is much more mature than Google Drive’s. Dropbox offers clients for every platform, including Linux. Download and install the Dropbox package for your distribution to get started [Download](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) .

It also offers client for microsoft , mac [Link](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/)

**SpiderOak**

SpiderOak’s distinguishing feature is its support for encryption. Unlike Google Drive, Dropbox, and Ubuntu One, all files you upload to SpiderOak are encrypted on your computer before they’re uploaded. SpiderOak advertises that they’re stored in an encrypted form where not even SpiderOak’s employees can view them.

**Wuala**

Wuala, owned by external storage manufacturer LaCie, is another cloud storage service that offers a Linux client in addition to clients for other platforms. Like SpiderOak, Wuala distinguishes itself by offering local encryption of your files – they’re uploaded to and stored on Wuala’s servers in an encrypted form.

Wuala also offers 5 GB of storage for free. Another 3 GB is available through a referral system.

Copied from [Site](http://www.howtogeek.com/130465/4-alternatives-to-google-drive-for-linux/)

Comment: Ubuntu One is end supported

Comment: Somehow Seafile always gets forgotten. Its "dropbox on steroids" and allows you to host your own (which I do). Its major advantage is that it allows you to encrypt everything. There is also a cloud offering at https://seacloud.cc/ if setting up your own server is too complicated. Clients for Mac, Windows, and Linux

Comment: Wuala has already shut down. More information is available on Wikipedia: https://goo.gl/00M2KZ

Answer (score 1):

I run 3 machines, 2 running Windows with only one running Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.  Although it is not perfect, I simply make it a routine to log into outlook.com or onedrive.com to access files on the Ubuntu machine.  It is necessary when creating links to sharing files with the public anyway, which I do periodically.  So it's a small effort to log in for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but it's in dev. Pls keep to follow this topic: [To Install OneDrive on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489246/to-install-onedrive-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment653758_489246)

Answer (score -1):

[The Microsoft OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com) website allows access to onedrive content. Documents can be edited with office online. I like this approach best since office online is 100% compatible with paid versions of Office.

Comment: don't be surprised if Microsoft products are hated here!

Comment: The original question is "how to install OneDrive on ubuntu?" Is is the only answer that gets onedrive access in ubuntu. And it is the one I have been happily using for over a year now. Thanks for explaining the anit-mircosoft attitude to me.