# How to install a skydrive client?

Tags: software-installation

Is there a way to setup Skydrive sync service on Ubuntu?

According to winehq I can not use wine to install skydrive so I am looking for a way to install it on Linux

Comment: I too have searched for a while for skydrive on ubuntu but could not find any option, not even third party options like Gdrive and regarding wine Skydrive I dont think it works but if you give it a shot let me know the result.

Comment: Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l55z4Mdf7w), here's [an article](http://itsfoss.com/skydrive-ubuntu-1304/), basically use [storagemadeeasy.com](http://storagemadeeasy.com/), download their client and sign in to your skydrive account.

Comment: @Back.Slash read my answer

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft changed the name to OneDrive now from SkyDrive.

Check the below link for using OneDrive in Linux.

http://itsfoss.com/skydrive-ubuntu-1304/

Comment: Please include full instructions in your answer and consider posting in here: http://askubuntu.com/q/433771/40581