# To Install OneDrive on Ubuntu

Tags: sync, cloud

To install OneDrive on Ubuntu, I've followed the instruction from here: [OneDrive-D Syncs Files to and from Microsoft](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/one-drive-ubuntu-integration?utm_source=feedly&utm_reader=feedly&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=one-drive-ubuntu-integration)

The installation seems right, till the end, when the "preferences" window appear, I clicked on the "Connect to the OneDrive.com" buttion:
[image]

An error occured:

> :~$ onedrive-prefs
>   NOT SANDBOXED
>   [ERROR:flash/platform/pepper/common/pep_process.cpp(19)] CHECK(g_process_type == PROCESS_TYPE_UNKNOWN) failed
>   java version "1.7.0_55"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
>   Aborted (core dumped)

How to solve it?

Comment: The install script does not mention Java. I think it would be best if you asked the devs directly: https://github.com/xybu92/onedrive-d/issues

Comment: Do you have java installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while till today, I've just tried again and everything's fine, It's running.
I think, there's a difference here, I installed the java7 by following from the instruction: [ORACLE JAVA INSTALLER CONFLICTING WITH APT BUG FIXED [UBUNTU 14.04]](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/oracle-java-installer-conflicting-with.html)

Answer (score 4):

I've written a [Java Client for OneDrive](https://github.com/wooti/onedrive-java-client) which might be a good alternative if you continue to have problems.