# How to sync OneDrive on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. How can I sync my OneDrive account on Ubuntu 14.04?
I know that OneDrive is a Microsoft cloud storage service and that Linux is not  supported.
But there is a a tool called "OneDrive-D".  How can install and use "OneDrive-D"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [@terdon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433771/how-to-install-onedrive-on-ubuntu-13-10-x64/433773#433773) said Onedrive-D is still under development.
Alternatively you can use [other cloud storage services](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433771/how-to-install-onedrive-on-ubuntu-13-10-x64/433776#433776).
Here is the instruction on how to install "OneDrive-D":

Step1: Download [the program from GitHub](https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d-old).

Step2: Extract the contents of the `.zip` file and run the installer from “onedrive-d-master.”

For that Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute:

```
cd ~/Downloads
ls
unzip onedrive-d-old-future.zip
cd onedrive-d-old-future
./install.sh
```

**Note** 1: I used `ls` command to list files in that folder and to avoid mistakes in file names.SInce there is another [new project](https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d) for same purpose.

**Note** 2: onedrive-d need python-**3**. Refer [here](https://github.com/xybu/onedrive-d) for prerequisites,but all necessary softwares will be  installed ,during installation process.So no need to worry about prerequisites.

Step 3: After installation you will see message like this:

```
onedrive-d installed successfully.
Please run command `onedrive-pref` to set up the program.
```

Now open terminal and run:  `onedrive-pref`

[image: Imgur]

Open the link in browser and enter your user id and password.

you will see prompt like this :

[image: Imgur]

Click on <kbd>YES</kbd>. Then copy the link and paste it in terminal.You will see message like this:

```
onedrive-d has been successfully authorized
```

Next,you need to adjust settings,if you want to keep default settings just press **n** .If you want to change press **y** and adjust.

Example:

```
(STEP 2/4) Do you want to specify path to local OneDrive repository? [Y/n] y
 Please enter the abs path to sync with your OneDrive (default: /home/[name]/OneDrive):
 Path successfully set.
(STEP 3/4) Do you want to change the numeric settings? [Y/n] n
 Skipped.
 (STEP 4/4) Do you want to edit the ignore list file? [Y/n] n
 Skipped
 All steps are finished.
```

Finally ,`onedrive-d --help` for commands.

`onedrive-d [command]`

```
Commands:
     start    Start the daemon.
     stop     Stop the daemon.
     restart  Stop then start the daemon.
     status   Get the status of the daemon.
```

Comment: Note: this only works for personal Onedrive accounts. Onedrive for Business is not supported by this library. See https://askubuntu.com/q/804301/367990 for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found more suitaible way of accessing and mounting OneDrive in Ubuntu (16.04 in my case) with Rclone-Browser

1. Download the Rclone application here and install it on your system: (the version in the standard Ubuntu repository only works for OneDrive personal edition.)
   https://rclone.org/downloads/  or directly from this for Ubuntu 64-bit systems: https://downloads.rclone.org/rclone-current-linux-amd64.deb

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i rclone-current-linux-amd64.deb
   ```
2. Rclone-browser

   Download the rclonebrowser from here: https://github.com/mmozeiko/RcloneBrowser/releases or install via a PPA (not yet for Ubuntu 18.04)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mmozeiko/rclone-browser
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt install rclone-browser
   ```

After installing both packages, start rclone-browser from the Dash.

[image]

> select n for new remote and give it any name that suits you. Onedrive would be fine.

Select 18 Onedrive (number can change)

leave blank twice

select personal or business

select Y if you are running a normal desktop system.

Now the browser should open and you can login in your onedrive account

now return to the terminal and conform with Y

press Q to exit and return to the rclone-browser and press the refresh button.

> Now you should see your onedrive account and  you can open it by double clicking

You are now able to mount it and see it in Nautilus. It is NOT a locally available filesystem. It is still remote. Some programs can read and write to this remote drive, and some don't. A workaround is to open a secon TAB in Nautilus, copy the files you need to the second TAB. Use them from there and copy them back afterwards.

<sub>**Source:** [Rclone and Rclone-Browser](https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/home/ubuntu-17-10/cloud-storage)</sub>

Comment: as I wrote in first sentence - it works and I like it