# How to use online account to control my onedrive?

Tags: 17.10, online-accounts

i have my microsoft account setup. Now how can i make use of it to access my onedrive files. It doesnot show up in nautilus.. Where can i access those **documents**?

[image]

Comment: Try using a terminal sync application called onedrive-d .
It is quite easy to config [Step by step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676210/how-to-sync-onedrive-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: what is the use of online accounts then if i use onedrive-d?

Comment: It is not a duplicate! I have the same question. It is not about how to use onedrive-d!